# error: use of '@import' when modules are disabled

Tags: objective-c, jazzy

I am running into these errors when running the following command

```
15:08:48 - tito@lt0311-2 Jazzy(master)> be jazzy --objc --umbrella-header Jazzy/SDK.h --theme apple --framework-root . --sdk iphoneos --module FyberSDK
/Users/tito/Documents/workspace/fyber/Jazzy/Jazzy/SDK.h:9:1: error: use of '@import' when modules are disabled
/Users/tito/Documents/workspace/fyber/Jazzy/Jazzy/Enum.h:9:1: error: use of '@import' when modules are disabled
/Users/tito/Documents/workspace/fyber/Jazzy/Jazzy/Enum.h:14:36: error: function definition declared 'typedef'
/Users/tito/Documents/workspace/fyber/Jazzy/Jazzy/Enum.h:14:9: warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
/Users/tito/Documents/workspace/fyber/Jazzy/Jazzy/Enum.h:18:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MyEnumA'
/Users/tito/Documents/workspace/fyber/Jazzy/Jazzy/Enum.h:23:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MyEnumB'
/Users/tito/Documents/workspace/fyber/Jazzy/Jazzy/Enum.h:28:5: error: use of undeclared identifier 'MyEnumC'
building site
jam out ♪♫ to your fresh new docs in `docs`
```

I checked and modules are enabled for the target

```
//:configuration = Debug
CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = NO
CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES

//:configuration = Release
CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = NO
CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES = YES

//:completeSettings = some
CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES
CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES
CLANG_MODULES_AUTOLINK
```

I am using the following version of jazzy

```
15:08:46 - tito@lt0311-2 Jazzy(master)> be jazzy -v
jazzy version: 0.7.0
```

I created a simple project that can reproduce the issue
https://github.com/TitouanVanBelle/JazzySampleProject